# Page hanging half-way in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

With the most recent upgrade to Chrome, my client is experiencing a very strange condition when his website's front page occasionally hangs half-way, completely preventing the browser from communicating with the said website until the hung tab is closed (so, opening a new tab next to the stuck one and trying to access the same address results in no content being received at all).

The version of problematic Chrome browser is 26.0.1410.43 beta, which was automatically installed for the majority of user base. Operating system is not affecting the case, as the same results had been seen under Windows and Mac OS X.

The website in question is located here: http://vmnews.ru

It is heavy, but other browsers seem to handle it quite well without hanging.

Do you have any suggestions as to how to troubleshoot Chrome-related issues if they cannot be repeated reliably, and only occur every other refresh or once in two or three attempts to load a page?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would say: I don't support beta versions of user agents unless you are going to double the pay

Comment: What if the pay is doubled and thus out of the question?

Comment: It's still most likely a browser bug and thus very difficult to diagnose (and possibly too localised as a question, as a side note)

Comment: Open Chrome's task manager and keep trying to reproduce it. Also disable plugins and flash and see whether the problem persists. But in all honesty the fact that the thing is Beta means the problem just might not be resolvable

Comment: plugins are, quite surprisingly, completely gone from this version of Chrome, I've seen this mentioned by other users several times.

Comment: are you using any prefixed features new in the beta?

Comment: Jan — certainly nothing specific for this beta, website didn't aim at any specific browser, Chrome just autoupdated itself and is now giving us a headache.

Comment: PeeHaa — I have reproduced the bug with Task Manager open, it gives me 10 frames/s, 0 CPU and 0 Network usage. After a while Chrome says that the page is not responsive and asks if I want to close it down. Any specific direction in the Task Manager I should investigate?